# php javascript onclick value change

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to remove the "http" if it is put in the url part of the input link, before the data is sent.

**this my input code look onclick=**

```
<input style="    outline: none;" type="button" onclick="formatText ('link:url');" class="btn btn-yeni" value="link"/>
```

**This my javascript code (the received data is sent to another file and replaced.)**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatText(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
 Field.value += '(' + tag + ')';
}
</script>
```

what i want to do If the input value is "link: http: //example.com" I would like to change it and post it as "link: example.com".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try in your url string :

```js
var result = url.replace(/(\w+:|^)\/\//, '');
```

`result` variable will hold "link : example.com" in place of "link : http://example.com"

Comment: Onclick does not work when I write this between the codes. the operation of the system is as follows; OnClick is sending data to the textarea field. then this data is posted with submit. I want to remove the http tag in onclick before posting. thanks, but the code you gave did not work.

Comment: is `document.getElementById('entry_girdi')`  the element that hold the url value ?

Comment: yes but onclick does not work when I write your code between JavaScript codes at the top.

Comment: if you replace `var val = Field.value;` line with this line `var val = Field.value.replace(/(\w+:|^)\/\//, '')` what happens ? <br> and you'll need only this part if you want only to remove the "http://" string from `url` then you can return it as `return val + '(' + tag + ')'`

Comment: for `url` i mean the `Field.value` which hold the `url` that you want to format. sorry for not being clear :). also this regex will help you even if the url has "https://" ;)

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
function formatText(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
var val = Field.value.replace(/(\w+:|^)\/\//, '');
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
 Field.value += '(' + tag + ')';
}
</script>`  I changed it this way but it still does not work. Where do I add the line starting with return?

Comment: try this : <br> `function formatText(tag) { 
  var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi'); 
  var val = Field.value.replace(/(\w+:|^)\/\//, ''); 
  var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart,Field.selectionEnd); 
  var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart); 
  var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length); 
  return val += '(' + tag + ')'; 
} ` cause you still returning `Field.value` that hold the same old value. you can check this simple example https://jsfiddle.net/rvpfd2ak/3/

Comment: thanks i tried your code but this time the onclick that populates the textarea field does not work. I need to have a value of "**(link: url)**" in the text field.

Comment: you can simply `return '('+tag+' : ' +val+')'` i think. can you try it ? <br> you can recheck here https://jsfiddle.net/rvpfd2ak/5/

Comment: hoh, not working. This job really tired me. Why onclick does not work for you.

Comment: no idea but when i've tried this example https://jsfiddle.net/rvpfd2ak/9/ it's works. can you check that ?

Comment: just to be sure if i click "link" button  i should get "(link:[my url without http]") or "bkz" button i should get the same result but in place of "link" i got "bkz" ?

Comment: because it's a comment line. more than one thing can be added. (link: http: //example.com) and (bkz the marten) or the gizli bkz (marten).  the thing that I want to do (link: http: //example.com) is the destruction of the http tag. and it is posting like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace()` function to replace part of a string.

```js
function formatText(tag) {
  var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
  Field.value = Field.value.replace("http://", "");
  Field.value += '(' + tag + ')';
}
```

Comment: He'll have to remove https too eventually

Comment: Why did you delete the lines I selected? I am sending data to another file using these lines. `var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);`

Comment: The code never used any of those variables, and they didn't seem relevant to the question. You can add them back in your complete application.